# I am getting this error on my code

Tags: android, sqlite

"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "on": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE SubjectTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,subject_name TEXT,on_monday INTEGER,on tuesday INTEGER,on_wednesday INTEGER,on_thursday INTEGER,on_Friday INTEGER);"

Comment: `,on tuesday` space in the column name.

Comment: @AkashPal, this time it is completely enough to see the error to understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that the SQL has a syntax error which is caused by the column definition `on Tuesday INTEGER`. **`ON`** is an SQLite keyword so it cannot be a column name unless forced e.g. `[on] Tuesday INTEGER`  would work (*although the column type will be Tuesday INTEGER*, which is probably not an issue).

You probably want the column name to be `on_Tuesday` so you should change the the SQL to be :-

```
CREATE TABLE SubjectTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,subject_name TEXT,on_monday INTEGER,on_tuesday INTEGER,on_wednesday INTEGER,on_thursday INTEGER,on_Friday INTEGER);
```

To implement this change you will need to ensure that the SQL is run. If the SQL is invoked via the `onCreate` method you should note that `onCreate` only runs automatically once when the database is created. Typically the way to force 'onCreate' to run is to delete the App's data or uninstall the App. An alternative may be to increase the version number, this requires that the `onUpgrade` has been coded so that the `onCreate` method will be called.